# Bootstrap how to float left a column to the top of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I float a column to right of the all above columns which are contained inside the same row.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row content">
  <div class="col-md-8 first-content">
    Some content
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 second-content">
    Some other content
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 float-right-top">
    This content need to float left
  </div>
</div>
```

Please refer the image to get clear picture
[image]

Comment: I see the same structure following up here, check the snippet in full screen. What do you mean by above all columns?

Comment: so, do u want to make the divs like the image? True?

Comment: @bhansha above all column means if there are many columns of width col-8 like third-content, fourth-content and so on.. then i need the column of width col-4 to float right and should align with first-content

Comment: @salman image and text both

Comment: @LalasMuathasim can you read my answer and give me a feedback?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `position: absolute`, `right: 0;` and `top: 0;` to `float-right-top` class.

HTML:

```
<div class="row content">
  <div class="col-md-8" first-content>
    Some content
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 second-content">
    Some other content
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 float-right-top">
    This content need to float left
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.float-right-top {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/8Lurbc78/

Comment: Thanks .. absolute positioning is something i'm trying to avoid.  But this method works thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about nesting the rows? Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/p3qrexxe/

**HTML**

```
<div class="row content">
  <div class="col-md-8 nomargin">
    <div class="col-md-12 first-content">
      Some content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 second-content">
      Some other content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 nomargin">
    <div class="col-md-12 float-right-top">
      This content need to float left
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 float-right-top2">
    This content need to float left 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nomargin {padding: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is **the class content which you used messed the css**

In every bootstrap row you have 12 columns. Now look at the code. You have assigned 8 columns to the first content `class="col-md-8 first-content"` so
12-8=4 Therefore, only 4 columns remain for you, and you have assigned these 4 columns to the third `div`. Notice, that by default float is left. And everything starts from left. Therefore it would be placed in the right hand side of the `row`

**If you add extra space using margin between the divs then automatically it would be moved to the extra row in the below**

so make sure for all dives you have

```
margin :0px;
```

Here is the complete code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-8">
            Some content
          </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            This content need to float left
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            Some other content
          </div>

  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

**What is wrong with ur code too?**

You have set 2 `div`s with `col-8` in the same row. So, the browser calculates it as `8+8=16`, and it understands also `16>12` (12 is maximum columns which you can have in a `row`). Therefore, it cannot afford it so it makes an extra `row`, and put your second `div` and allocate 8 columns to it in the second row.

Please see the below image:

[image]

Comment: @Lalas Muathasim I guess you didn't like my solution? What is going wrong?

Comment: sorry for late reply.. This particular code should definitely work but what if the content with col-md-4 happens after all the col-md-8 divs. Then if we float:right the col-md-4 right, this particular column aligns with the col-md-8 happening immediately above it not right aligned with the first happening col-md-8

Comment: @LalasMuathasim if my answer was helpful, please upvote it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/qeu3t8gk/

```css
.left{min-height:500px;}
.float-right-top{height200px; background:blue;top:0px;position:fixed;right: 0; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row content ">
  <div class="col-md-8 left" >
    Some content
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 left">
    Some other content
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 float-right-top">
    This content need to float left
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've updated @StaXter answer.

create to parent div for left and right and place your content inside them.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row content">
  <div class="right">
      <div class="col-md-8" first-content>
        Some content
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 second-content">
        Some other content
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="left">
      <div class="col-md-4 float-right-top">
        This content need to float left
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.right,.left{
  float:left;
}
.right {
  width:70%
}
.left{
  width:30%;
}
```